# iOS 7 - UITextField Clip Subviews Isn't Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, uistoryboard

I am porting an iOS 6 application to iOS 7 and have noticed some UI bugs that I have bad some issues solving.  The largest would be one I found in the UITextView.  In iOS 6 I have a UITextField that has a varying amount of dynamic text in it.  I have a function that resizes the table view cell around the text view but I found it hard to accurately predict the size of the UITextView so I just disabled clipping and let the text overflow outside the UITextView.  I put a buffer between the cell view and the text and thought the problem was solved.  When I ported the application to iOS 7 this no longer worked.  I can't seem to find a way to have the UITextView not clip it's subviews and overflow the text as it did in iOS 6.  I have tried setting `setClipsToBounds:NO` both in the UIStoryboard and programatically, and have also tried disabling the layer mask with `setMasksToBounds:NO`.  Nothing seems to work, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I ended up fixing this issue using the iOS 7 constraints.  I clipped the bottom of the UITextView to the outer view and removed the pinned height.  This allowed the UITextView to resize appropriately.